# Processes synchronization

Tags: c, process, synchronization, semaphore

```
write_semaphore -> 1
```

**1-Process A**

```
main(){
    int a[50],i;

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        //wait(write_semaphore)
        x = a[i];
    }
}
```

**N-Processes B**

```
main(){
    int b[50],i;

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        b[i] = x;
    }
}
```

I have 1 A process and N B processes. A process writes an element of the a array to the shared variable x. Then ALL the N B processes must read the data and store it to ther local array. When all the N B processes store it, then A process can finally assign the next element of the array to the variable x.

Example:

```
 // A process
 i = 0
 x = a[0];

 // B processes

 b[0] = x; // To ALL

 // A process (I can continue now)
 i = 1;
 ...
```

How can i synchronize it using semaphores? The last process B that reads the data shoud signal the write semaphore in order the A process to write the next element. How can i know when every B process read the data?

Comment: There's no shared variable `x` in the code above.  There is a local variable `x` in each of the `main()` functions, but they are 100% wholly unrelated to each other other than by coincidence of name.  You're going to need to create some shared memory for the processes to share, and then the semaphore(s) for the processes to use -- one for signalling 'value ready in x' and one for signalling 'value read from x; send next'.

Comment: my bad. variable x should not be defined inside the mains.

Comment: Even if `x` is made global, the global `x` in one program is wholly unrelated to the global `x` in the other program.  You have to create shared memory for variables to be shared.

Comment: Yes, assume they exist..

Comment: This is more like pseudocode..

Comment: You'll end up with a pointer `int *px;` in each process that is initialized to point to the (same) shared memory.  As I already said, you'll need two semaphores if you want to be sure that the reader reads every value before the writer writes the next.  If you don't care about 'lost' (unread) values, then an inter-process mutex is sufficient, and a single semaphore can be used as the inter-process mutex.  What are your actual requirements?  Have you worked out how to create shared memory?  How to create and initialize semaphores?

Comment: This is not an answer, but a helpful place to go is to investigate OpenMP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP

Comment: A the end every process B must have a copy of the a array. I am more interested on how the synchronization works (wait-signal) and not how is this implemented in C.

Comment: And I see I didn't read enough of the question; you have multiple B processes, all of which must read the new value.  You'll need to set up protected counters in some shape or form, so that A can say to N copies of B 'there is data ready' and then detect when it has N responses from B processes 'got that; ready for the next'.  I'd have to do some thinking about it, but you've probably got a book to read that discusses the options for semaphores, etc.

Comment: Maybe use an array of semaphores with size N in which every semaphore is initialized to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Use a counting semaphore, like this:

Process A loop (1 instance):

1. Write data.
2. Decrement semaphore N times.

Process B loop (N instances):

1. Read data.
2. Increment semaphore once.

The semaphore must be decremented once per instance of B, and if each B increments it once, this will have the effect of blocking A until N completions of B.

Making B wait to read again until A has written is left as an exercise.  :)  You  could do it with N semaphores (because the same B must not be allowed to read twice in a single iteration of A); I'm not sure if there's a leaner way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using an array of semaphores. I am not sure if it's 100% correct.

```
sem write_semaphore -> 1
sem counter_mutext -> 1
sem read[M] -> 0 // every element 0. (pseudocode)
int counter = 0;
```

**1-Process A**

```
main(){
    int a[50],i;

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        wait(write_semaphore)
        x = a[i];

        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            up(read[j]);  //everyone can now read 
    }
}
```

**N-Processes B**

```
main(){
    int b[50],i;
    int index;    // the index of my semaphore in the array

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        down(read[index]); // i block until A signals me
        b[i] = x;
        down(counter_mutex);
        counter++;
        if (counter == M) // everyone read
            up(write_semaphore); 
            counter = 0;
        up(counter_mutex);
    }
}
```

This solution requires that every B process knows its index of the semaphore array that's why I am not sure if it's correct or not.